# How to execute more than one query on one table at the same time

Tags: python, mysql, database, mysql-python

Can i execute more than one query on one table at the same time?
for example i want to have 4 different searches on one the table at the same time.
like this `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE id=1`,`SELECT name FROM TABLE WHERE id=4`.
i want to execute all of them at the same time in separate command.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could use `WHERE IN (...)` logic:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
ORDER BY id;
```

The only possibile difficultly would be keeping track of whence `id` each record appears in the result set.  Using an `ORDER BY id` clause might be one way to deal with this Python, as you could then iterate in order, and retrieve the set of records for each `id` value.

Comment: @Strawberry ...and a union might even perform better using an index.